# Why do we "drive to the United Nations" but "drive to United Airlines"?

Tags: grammatical-number, proper-nouns

I understand why we "drive to Microsoft" but must "drive to *the* United Nations".

But why do we "drive to United Airlines" rather than "drive to *the* United Airlines"?

Comment: I would think you'd be driving mostly to "the United Airlines terminal".  I'm not sure under what conditions you'd just be driving to "United Airlines".  In my example, the word "the" is there because of the "terminal."

Comment: @Steven Littman One terminal bus driver talking to another. Or, "walk to United Airlines" when walking inside to airport. The key point is no article. Versus, "drive to the United Nations".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because *The United Nations* is called The United Nations", not "United Nations" *, while *United Airlines* is called "United Airlines".

Going beyond this, the UN is an organisation of nations, while UA is a company that chose a name.

**Edit**: @fundagain points out that the official name of the UN is not "The United Nations". This is true. But I still maintain that it is **called** "The United Nations".

The "NOW" (News on the Web) corpus has 24,393 instances of "The United Nations VERB" against 4,018 for "(not-'the') United Nations VERB" - but a quick inspection indicates that many of the latter have been mistagged, and a word which *could* be a verb has wrongly been categorised as such: for example "United Nations report". I estimate there are no more than a couple of hundred genuine examples. Of course when "United Nations" is used as a modifier in a noun phrase (eg "United Nations report") you wouldn't expect the article.

Comment: Are you certain it is  called "The United Nations" and not "United Nations"? The United Nations home page is titled "United Nations" and similarly on Wikipedia.  Wikipedia talks of "the **United Nations**".

Comment: Fair comment, @fundagain. See my edit to my answer.

Comment: Let me get you correctly. There exists no proper noun "United Nations". Hence writing "the United Nations" is not really grammatically correct (the article cannot act on "United Nations" since "United Nations"  doesn't exist). Rather, there exists only a proper noun "The United Nations", with "the United Nations" being a common simplification when writing the proper noun down.

Comment: Hmm, @fundagain, have to think about that. No, I don't think that is what I'm saying, because _United Nations_ is used without the article when it is attributive (eg _a United Nations report_).  That fact seems to make it clear that _United Nations_ is indeed a proper noun. But when it is stand-alone (not used attributively) it nearly always seems to require _the_. It seems to mirror exactly some country names that are definite descriptions: _The United States_, _The United Kingdom_, _The Soviet Union_, _The Russian Federation_ (though the last two may be shortened to one word attributively).

Comment: I don't think we need to get into that, because you have correctly answered why "United Airlines" behaves like "Microsoft" rather than "United Nations". That was my question, not why "United Nations" takes the article (which would be a duplicate question anyway). So I am accepting your answer.